# How many tries to get higher number than uniform random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I came across the following problem, and don't know how to solve it:

Player 1 samples from the Uniform(0,1) distribution. Then Player 2 repeatedly samples from
the same distribution until he obtains a number higher than Player 1’s. How many samples
is he expected to make?

Comment: What have you tried? I think the answer may be surprisingly high

Comment: Consider the difference between the results: $P_2 - P_1$. It has the range $-1 \ldots 1$. In order to succeed, this difference has to be positive.

Comment: Perhaps you could find the expected number of trials until player 2 first exceeds some fixed number $p_0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a second solution. Conditioned on player $1$'s pick ($U_0$), $N$ follows a Geometric distribution with parameter $1-U_0$. Hence, $\mathbb{E}(N|U_0) = \frac{1}{1-U_0}$. So,
$$\mathbb{E}(N) = \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{1-U_0}\right) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x} dx = \infty~.$$

Comment: Both your solutions are correct, though I slightly feel Rik could have benefited from trying to solve it

Comment: Thank you this makes sense to me - this is what I had in mind in my comment below as well.

Comment: @Henry, yes, I agree. May be thinking of the intuition is also an interesting question, which I am leaving. The intuition should be as less Mathematical as possible though!

Comment: @Probabilist : very very nice solution....I am sick, I fixed a single value for player 1.... :(

Comment: Is your answer contradictory to this one here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1835385/458420

Answer (score 1):

If Player 1 drew $p$, the expectation of the number of drawings by Player 2 is (with $q:=1-p$)

$$1\,q+2\,pq+3\,p^2q+\cdots=\frac 1q.$$

Then as the drawings of Player 1 are equiprobable, the requested expectation is

$$\int_0^1\frac{dp}{1-p}$$ which diverges.

Comment: Is your answer contradictory to this one here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1835385/458420

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be the number of samples player 2 makes until he ontains a number higher than player 1. I will use the formula:
$$\mathbb{E}(N) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(N \geq k)~.$$
Now, the event $N \geq k$ is same as saying that in the first $k-1$ trials, player 2 obtained less than player 1 (less than and less than equal to don't matter here, since the random variables are continuous). So, let $U_1,\ldots,U_{k-1}$ be the uniform numbers player 2 picks in the first $k-1$ trials, and let $U_0$ be player 1's pick. Then, $U_0, U_1,\ldots, U_{k-1}$ are iid. $U(0,1)$, and we are interested in the probability:
$$\mathbb{P}(U_0 > \max\{U_1,\ldots,U_{k-1}\})~.$$
The above probability is clearly $1/k$. Hence, we have:
$$\mathbb{E}(N) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} = \infty~.$$
Strange, right? Now, try to think of an intuition, why this expected number of trials is $\infty$.

Comment: The marginal probability that Player 2 needs $k$ trials to first exceed Player 1 is $\frac1{k(k+1)}$, which is consistent with your result, but I am not sure this is really intuitive